# How to search page for words and highlight them (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, highlight

I currently have an array of user inputted words and respective highlight colors stored in objects (below is the function that constructs the array upon user button click and input):

```
//DECLERATIONS////
var placementId = 0;
var searchList = [];

///FUNCTION THAT ADDS A NEW WORD TO SEARCHLIST////////
function addWord(userWord, userColor){ //append new word to find and highlight
    var wordAndColorPair = {
        word: userWord,
        color: userColor,
        id: placementId
    }
    searchList.push(wordAndColorPair);
}

///////BELOW IS THE EVENT THAT ACTUALLY CONSTRUCTS THE ARRAY//////////

$('.color-element').click(function(){ //adding new word-color pairs
    var userInput = $('#input-word').val();
    if(userInput !== ''){ //only if user enteres text:
        var newWord = document.createElement("span"); //create a new search word tile

        newWord.classList.add('search-word'); //add the class search-word to it
        newWord.textContent = userInput; //make its text value equal to the input

        var colorId = $(this).attr('id'); //set its bacckground color to a copy of the button clicked
        $(newWord).css("background-color", colorId);

        $(newWord).attr('id', placementId); //set this new elements unique ID for delection purposes

        $('.display-array').append(newWord); //append the child to the DOM

        addWord(userInput, colorId, placementId); //add the word to the search list - increment placementId for future words
        placementId ++;

        $('#input-word').val(''); //reset the input field
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
});
```

What I am having trouble with is being able to search the whole page and actually highlight the words seen in the array. What I have so far is:

```
$('.search').click(function(){ //when the search button is clicked
    var i;
    for(i =0; i< searchList.length; i++){//for each word user inputted:
        $("*").contents().each(function() {
            var word = searchList[i].word;
            var regex = new RegExp('(\\b'+word+'\\b)', 'gi');
            if(this.nodeType == 3){ //if text
                $(this).html(text.replace(regex, " <span style = 'background-color: " + searchList[i].color + " ;'> " + searchList[i].word + "</span>"));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This, however, does not seem to be working, any assistance is much appreciated!

HTML for DOM reference:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa:700|Roboto+Condensed:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Word Finder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">

    <meta name="description" content="Word Finder Chrome Extension">
    <meta name="author" content="Aalok Borkar">
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        this is a test of the funcitonality TEXT text text text hello

    </p>

    <div class = "input">
        <div class = "word">
            Word <input type = "text" id = 'input-word' placeholder= "Jim Halpert"></input>
        </div>

        <div class = "color-palette">
            <!-- on click: clear text input, add color, append search array / display array -->
            <button class = "color-element" id = "red"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "orange"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "yellow"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "green"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "blue"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "violet"></button>
            <button class = "color-element" id = "pink"></button>               
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "display">
        <p> Words to Search</p>
        <div class = "display-array">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class = "search">Search</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We don't see a sample of dom tree ?

Comment: I added the HTML code

Comment: and in the latter function, text would be for example `$('#input-word').val()` ?

Comment: Yes, that is how you would access the user's input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need to be done that way:

```
$(this).parent().html($(this).parent().html().replace($(this).text(),$(this).text().replace(regex, " <span style = 'background-color: " + searchList[i].color + " ;'>" + searchList[i].word + "</span> ")));
```

This is because when you change the `innerHTML` directly you will mess the dom structure and lose the html format, when you change the text solely you would have a a sanitized DOM inside quotes, so it should be solved one way by modifying the text part inside the inner html.

[see it here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ahBNiuZQjb43dysXQkSx?p=preview)

Comment: is there a simpler way to do this, as I am very confused by the answer you have provided

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I added a class to your `<p>` element, but you probably don't have to do that. I just did it for ease of access on my part. The biggest thing, if I understood your question right, was your search function. IMO, you need to look at each word and compare it to the search array. Find the word that matches and wrap it in something that you can apply a style to. In my case, I chose a `<span>` tag. Fiddle below code.

```
// HTML Modification
<p class="searchable">
  this is a test of the functionality TEXT text text text hello
</p>

$('.search').click(function() { //when the search button is clicked
  var original = $('.searchable').html().trim();
  var searchable = original.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < searchList.length; i++) { //for each word user 
inputted:
    for (var s = 0; s < searchable.length; s++) {
      if (searchable[s] == searchList[i].word) {
        searchable[s] = "<span style='background:" + searchList[i].color + 
";'>" + searchList[i].word + "</span>";
      }
    }
  }

  rewrite(searchable);  //SEE BELOW
});

// This iterates over the searchable array
function rewrite(searchable) {
  var highlighted = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < searchable.length; i++) {
    highlighted += searchable[i] + "&nbsp;";
  } 
  $('.searchable').html(highlighted.trim());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5v3aqrzd/